# Separating numbers to single cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to separate letters & numbers to individual cells in excel.
My example TYE123 - T to A1, Y to A2, E to A3, 1 to A4 etc.
I have multiple rows with different amount of characters TYE123, CP1045, TCDE54.

Comment: Do it by VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code will do the job:

```
Sub SplitStuff()
'Update 20140318
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "SingleLettersExample"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In InputRng
    xValue = Rng.Value
    xRow = Rng.Row
    For i = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
        OutRng.Cells(xRow, i).Value = VBA.Mid(xValue, i, 1)
    Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How to use:

1. Create a presentation in the `.xlsm` file-format
2. Hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
   to open the Microsoft Visual Basic editor
3. Click "ThisWorkbook" and paste the VBA code in the Window
4. Then press F5 key to run this code, and enter for the prompt boxes:

   - Range : `$A1:$A3` (for the example 3 rows)
   - Output : `$B1`

[image]